# Beginner Basics; thank you in advance for your time and kind consideration

Tags: ip, networking

If PCs connected across the same broadcast domain can send and receive frames based on the MAC address and do not intend to leave the local area network, then why do they need an IP address? Since IP addresses are not helpful in interfacing with the layer 2 hardware attached to the local network.

Comment: On the contrary, IP addresses cover the whole internet. Routers use IP to figure out where to route data. IP aren't helpful in interfacing with the physical hardware on your local network. IPs are found at Layer3 - Network layer. IP are stored in your routing table(On your PC, on command line: type "route -n" or "route print").

Comment: There are many, many questions and answers about this subject on this forum.  You can search for them

Comment: Thanks Ron. I have been and still am. I actually read this one you posted before submitting my own. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The short answer to your question is, they don't.  When Ethernet, ArcNet and Token Ring were first developed, there was no IP, and devices did just fine.  But in order to route, you need an internetwork layer.